# Reading synchronised data from 2 serial USB ports concurrently in Python. Threading? Multiprocessing?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, pyserial

I'm building an autonomous rover controlled by a Raspberry Pi using RTK GPS navigation. I am using two separate U-Blox RTK GPS modules on the rover operating at 4Hz to get very accurate position and heading calculations and they are both connected to the Pi through USB ports. I'm using the pyserial library to read the NMAE sentences as they are output through USB. The problem I have encountered is that the serial data sent by each module is precisely synchronised and so while calling Serial.readline() for one port, the data sent to the other port is missed.

The basics of the code currently looks something like this:

```
`class GPS():
      def __init__(self,port,baud):
          self.gpsSerial = serial.Serial(port,baud)
          # init some variables
          return

      def read(self):
          NMEASentance = str(self.gpsSerial.readline())
          if NMEASentance not what_i_wanted_or_blank:
              return 0
          # do some processing, update vars
          return 1

frontGps = GPS(port1,baud)
rearGps = GPS(port2,baud)

while True:
    if frontGps.read():
       # grab the new data
    if rearGps.read():
       # grab the new data
```

What ends up happening is that while one serial port is being read and the data processed, the other is transmitting simultaneously and is missed. I have tried doing both reads one after the other and leaving the processing for later, but the problem persists.
How do i read both ports simultaneously? Will threading each serial read work (they will both still be running in the same process, and so won't be executed concurrently, right?)
If the solution is multiprocessing then could someone please post some skeleton code for me to follow because this problem is really doing my head in.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why do you have 2 GPSs please? Have you considered using separate processes feeding `gpsd`? https://www.linux-magazine.com/Issues/2018/210/Tutorial-gpsd

Comment: I'm using two so that the precise orientation of the rover is always known. With a base station this provides the GPS location of two fixed points on the rover with centimetre accuracy, thus giving orientation (and even pitch). The python code i wrote for a previous iteration using one gps and a compass worked perfectly, but using a compass introduced problems like being sensitive to the magnetic fields produced by the motors and having to be calibrated regularly. I've played around with gpsd but haven't invested the time to try and integrate it. I was hoping for a quick fix to python code

Comment: I am not sure what is causing the problem, so don't waste too much time following my (guessstimated) suggestions, but if no-one else is answering and you have time... you might consider starting 2 new, separate Python processes from your current main process. Create two multiprocessing queues first, and pass each new Python process one queue and let the new processes each simply repeatedly read a GPS in a loop and write whatever they get into a queue for the main process to pick up. Just an idea to make the 2 GPS units very independent.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks, I'll give that a go tomorrow morning. This sounds like a promising solution!

Comment: @MarkSetchell Bingo! Set up two processes to read from the serial ports and add them to a shared queue. Works as expected, thanks!

Comment: Excellent - well done. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

Would love to get some code on this:
Set up two processes to read from the serial ports and add them to a shared queue

I have a GPS serial loop running and need to add a second serial link for a magnetometer and needed a way to keep the two streams separate

Currently, working with a Neo6M GPS and noticed that the #GPRMC message is like a heartbeat that is transmitted once a second on each UTC second tick.

The #GPRMC is the GPS standard sentence that transmits **UTC time/date**
(and location, speed and heading) so it makes sense that it would be transmitted at UTC second = 00.00

After reading about the problem it occurred to me that all the GPS receivers are probably doing the same. So if you have any number of them powered up, they will all be synchronized.

If my theory is correct:
Armies of GPS-enabled pi soldier robots could be made to walk in step even though they are continents apart.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the code at the moment. From what i remember i first configured the gps so that only the RMC and GGA NMEA are output on serial, so that reduced the load significantly (only about 8 strings per second). I created a multiprocessed GPS class which initialises the serial connection and then in its run method for each loop i do serial.read(1) which waits until one byte is received, then serial.readline() to capture the rest of the string, processing it and puting relevant data into queue. Spawning two of these allowed my to capture everything sent over both serial ports